# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages when i apply site.pp ,currently using Ubuntu-22.04 and puppet-7.25.0

Tags: package-management, puppet

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install qemu-kvm' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.27) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Error: /Stage[main]/Libvirt::Install/Package[qemu-kvm]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install qemu-kvm' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qemu-kvm : Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.27) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: A quick look at what I'd expect to see (`qemu-system-x86 | 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.12  | jammy-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`) and it looks to me like issues with sources where you gave no details.  The package your message appears to be `qemu-system-x86 | 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.27       | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` so check your facts, sources etc... Are you sure you're using *jammy* or 22.04 as you state?

Comment: There is no actual question in your *question text*... Don't forget not everyone uses large screens or desktop PCs, and title text may NOT be viewable when the page is read; and your question is only pasted terminal text!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)